# Question About Tension

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

I'm currently going through [MIT OCW's Classical Mechanics Course](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/8-01sc-classical-mechanics-fall-2016/pages/week-2-newtons-laws/7-1-pushing-pulling-and-tension/). I'm a little confused by the section about tension in the course and would like to seek some clarification.

[image]

The course defines tension at arbitrary point p in a rope as follows. Suppose we cut a rope in two, around that point p. According to the course, "there will now be a third pair of forces acting between the left and right sections of the rope. Denote the force acting on the left section by F<sub>R,L</sub>(x<sub>p</sub>) and the force on the right section as F<sub>L,R</sub>(x<sub>p</sub>).
Tension is defined as the magnitude of either of these forces.

What's confusing me is why there would be a third pair of forces acting between the left and right sections of the rope.

To my understanding, this is because if we cut the rope in two, we can think of the rightmost section as pulling the leftmost section to the right. In other words, the rightmost section exerts a force F<sub>R,L</sub>(x<sub>p</sub>) on the leftmost section, resulting in an equal and opposite reaction F<sub>L,R</sub>(x<sub>p</sub>).

Is this the right way to understand it?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: @mmesser314 Thanks - appreciate it.